# Is it correct that std::filesystem::operator==() returns false when comparing two unc paths with different path separators?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, comparison, std-filesystem

I just fell over the following behavior of `std::filesystem::path` compiling with Visual Studio 16.0.0 and I wonder if it is correct.

```
#include <filesystem>

int main()
{
    std::filesystem::path absPath1("c:\\foo\\bar");
    std::filesystem::path absPath2("c:/foo/bar");

    bool absPathsAreEqual = absPath1 == absPath2; // absPathsAreEqual is true as expected.

    std::filesystem::path uncPath1("\\\\foo\\bar");
    std::filesystem::path uncPath2("//foo/bar");

    bool uncPathsAreEqual = uncPath1 == uncPath2; // uncPathsAreEqual is false which is a surprise for me.
}
```

I am no path expert so I am not sure if it makes sense that the paths are not equal in the second case.
So is this the correct behavior?

Comment: UNC paths only use the backslash character.  The `//foo/bar` is not a compliant UNC path.

Comment: [OT]: Raw string might be used to simplify escaping: `absPath1(R"(c:\foo\bar)");`

Comment: I think problem is that `////a/b/c` is equal to `/a/b/c` https://wandbox.org/permlink/gAXLDyiCT1G9mhIA and in case of UNC `\\a\b\c` it can't be done like that.

Comment: In this documetnation https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path they mention path roots `root-name(optional): identifies the root on a filesystem with multiple roots (such as "C:" or "//myserver").` This looks like a leading `//` should be valid.